# What does input_shape,input_dim and units indicate or mean while adding layers in a Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

Im new to keras and i was wondering if I could do some work regarding text classification using neural networks.
So i went ahead and got a data set regarding spam or ham and I vectorized the data using tfidf and converted the labels to a numpy array using the to_categorical() and managed to split my data into train and test each of which is a numpy array having around 7k columns.
This the code i used.

```
model.add(Dense(8,input_dim=7082,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8,input_dim=7082))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I dont know if im doing something totally wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction as to what i should change. 
The error thrown:
`Error when checking input: expected dense_35_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()`

Answer (score 1):

Dense layers doesn't seem to have any `input_dim` parameter according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/).

`input_shape` is a tuple and must be used in the first layer of your model. It refers to the shape of the input data.

`units` refers to the dimension of the output space, that is the shape of each output element processed by the dense layer.

In your case, if your input data has is of dimensionality 7082, this should work:

```
model.add(Dense(8,input_shape=(7082,),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thanks alot its working, the problem was with respect to my arrays. Could you direct me to a resource where i can research on these topics. I still dont understand as to how the '8' in the dense layers is used for.

Comment: I think you should study a little bit on neural networks. You can find plenty of blog posts and tutorial on the Internet on how to design and train neural networks. If you want a deeper understanding of the maths behind neural networks you can give a go at https://www.deeplearningbook.org/ , this is an online book that explains a lot about neural network. It has been written by some of the most famous researchers of the field (Goodfellow is the inventor of GANs and Bengio have been awarded last turing prize). You can mark the answer as accepted if it works.